# Linking URL with a Bluemix hosted app

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is it possible to route a URL to my BlueMix hosted app?

Any pointers will be more than appreciated.

Thanks,
Liora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep!

**Video:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG7UbOHywXc

There are two parts. First is the DNS settings and URL forwarding you'll need where you bought your domain. Second is the issue of routing, spaces and orgs.

From your dashboard, click your org's dropdown and choose Manage Organizations. Then click domains, and add domain. The domain is organization wide, which means you can link different subdomains to different applications. This becomes useful if you build your blog separate from your website and so forth. Now you've got a custom domain associated with your org, what's next?

Go back to your dashboard and click on your desired application. Then in the top right corner, you'll see a settings drop down for your application (not the notifications robot thingy). In the dropdown choose edit routes. Add a route for `www.mynewcustomdomain.com`. (You'll notice you can't leave the subdomain blank, I haven't figured out how to handle that, you probably can't point to your strict domain for load balancing reasons).

Okay, part two. Go to your domain name registrar. Find URL forwarding and forward `mynewcustomdomain.com` to `www.mynewcustomdomain.com`. Then go to your DNS settings and add a CNAME record which points `www.mynewcustomdomain.com` to the `appname.ng.bluemix.net` that Bluemix provides by default.

Wait a bit for DNS settings to propagate, then test things out.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/8855/how-to-get-your-custom-domain-up-and-running.html

Comment: It did. Look at www.lioramilbaum.me. Thanks.